# How to select a particular part of the line chart in chart js

Tags: angular, charts, chart.js, linechart

I want to select a particular part of line chart so that for that part I can update my other charts and display data accordingly.

```
<div class="card mb-4 ">
<div class="card-header">
    <i class="fa fa-area-chart me-1"></i>
    Frequency vs Acceleration
</div>
<div class="card-body">
    <canvas id="myLineChart" width="100%"  height="30"></canvas>

</div>
<div class="card-footer small text-muted">
    Updated on {{chartUpdateTime|date:'mediumDate'}} at {{chartUpdateTime|date:'shortTime'}}
</div>
```

My chart.ts file

```
ngOnInit():void{

var myLineChart = new Chart('myLineChart', {
type: 'line',

data: {
  labels: ["0Hz", "20Hz", "40Hz", "60Hz", "80Hz", "100Hz", "120Hz", "140Hz", "160Hz", "180Hz"],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Frequency',
    tension:0.4,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,120,214,1)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(0,120,214,1)',
    pointRadius: 3,
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0,120,214,1)',
    pointHoverRadius: 4,
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0,120,214,1)',
    pointHitRadius: 50,
    pointBorderWidth: 2,
    data: [10000, 30162, 26263, 18394, 18287, 28682, 31274, 33259, 25849, 24159],
  }],
},
options: {
  scales: {
    xAxis:{
      
      grid:{
        display:false
      },
      ticks:{
        maxTicksLimit:7,
        
      }
    },
    yAxis:{
      
      ticks:{
        maxTicksLimit:5
      },
      grid:{
        color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .125)"
      }
    }
   
  }
 
}
});
```

Current output
[image: img]

My requirement is that at any place in the graph if I press mouse then drag it to the right then it should make a rectangular box and once I release it it should give me the points on the x axis where the rectangular box was started and where it ended so that based on that range I can update my other graphs. The rectangular box should disappear once I have released the mouse. Please community help me out with this. If this cannot be done in chartjs please suggest a free library where this can be done easily.

Comment: You can use `chartjs-plugin-zoom` (see https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-zoom/latest/samples/drag/linear.html)

Comment: No actually what I want to do is when I select a part of the graph then it should show that part of the graph in another graph which I will place above this graph. That way the bottom graph shows the entire data and the top graph shows the part that is selected. Also based on this selection I want to update some more graphs